# getUserMedia throw error NavigatorUserMediaError: InvalidStateError

Tags: google-chrome-extension, getusermedia

I got streamId from desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia Api but getUserMedia failed

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: {
      mandatory: {
        chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
        chromeMediaSourceId: streamId
      }
    },
    video: {
      mandatory: {
        chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
        chromeMediaSourceId: streamId,
        maxWidth: window.screen.width,
        maxHeight: window.screen.height
      }
    }
  }).then(function(stream) {

    }).catch(function(err) {
       // The error show here
     console.log(err)
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: Sorry . I was edit description .The error show on catch

Comment: what error did you get.

Comment: @Kumar Error in response to tabCapture.capture: First parameter is required.

Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabCapture.capture: Extension has not been invoked for the current page (see activeTab permission). Chrome pages cannot be captured.

Comment: did you add `tabCapture` permission in manifest.json file.

Comment: yes. I added it

Answer (score 1):

As, navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia return you a promise. So, you have to use it like promise. Your function should be like this.

```
var obj = {
    audio: {
      mandatory: {
        chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
        chromeMediaSourceId: streamId
      }
    },
    video: {
      mandatory: {
        chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
        chromeMediaSourceId: streamId,
        maxWidth: window.screen.width,
        maxHeight: window.screen.height
      }
    }
  };

window.navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(obj).then(function(stream) {
    // Do your work with the stream
}).catch(function(err) {
   // Your error show here.
 console.log(err)
});
```

For more information you can look at here --> [Check it out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) Hope it helps